# Oracle 11g .DMP viewer

Tags: oracle, import

I have received a dump of a Oracle 11.2.0.2.0 db, which I'd like to export to some readable format like plain text, CSV, excel...

Is that possible in some sort of a simple way? I've found a few converters, but they're not free.

If nothing else, I did just install the latest Oracle Express Edition and Oracle SQL Developer, but I can't seem to find a way to import my .DMP file.
I've tried using the imp and impdp tools, but they both gave me an error:

**imp 'sys AS SYSDBA' file=dump.dmp full=yes log=implog.txt**

IMP-00038: Could not convert to environment character set's handle

**impdp 'sys AS SYSDBA' file=dump.dmp full=yes log=implog.txt**

ORA-39001: invalid argument value

ORA-39000: bad dump file specification

ORA-39088: file name cannot contain a path specification

UPDATE:

It seems I needed to copy the dump to "C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\admin\XE\dpdump" for the IMPDP to work. But now I get the following error message (or maybe just a warning, because as far I see, the tables were created and the data was imported?):

ORA-39083: Object type REFRESH_GROUP failed to create with error:

ORA-23421: job number 1389 is not a job in the job queue

Failing sql is:

BEGIN 
dbms_refresh.make('"DB"."TABLE"',list=>null,next_date=>null,interval=>null,implicit_destroy=>TRUE,lax=>FALSE,job=>1389,rollback_seg=>NULL,push_deferred_rpc=>TRUE,refresh_after_errors=>FALSE,purge_option => 1,parallelism => 0,heap_size => 0);
dbms_refresh.add(name=>'"DB"."TABLE"',list=>'"DB"."TABLE"',siteid=>0,export_db=>'XE');
 END;

Job "SYS"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" completed with 32 error(s) at 06:59:30

UPDATE 2:

Yeah, I've just checked via Toad for Oracle, and all the data was successfully imported. I also managed to export to excel file using the same application.

Comment: What line did you run in order to generate the errors?

Comment: Do you have NLS_LANG set? How did you receive the file - it's a binary format so it it possible it's been corrupted by an ASCI FTP or similar? Does running `imp` with `show=y` give you anything?

Comment: @Ben I've updated the question.
@AlexPoole I don't know. I've received it through email. `show=y` gives me the exact same error as before.

Comment: You have to create a directory first. In sqlplus: `create directory IMPDIR as '/path/to/the/file';`. Then repeat your previous `impdp` command-line, but add the parameter `DIRECTORY=IMPDIR`

Comment: ORA-39088: file name cannot contain a path specification indicates that your file name specification contains a path specification like file=C:\dump.dmp or something similiar. In your post the impdp command did not have such a path specification. This is strange. Do you show us the real command or did you remove the path in your post?

Comment: @miracle173 I've shown you the real command. I've copied the dump file to the same dir the imp/impdb was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to create a directory on the database.

```
Create or Replace Directory IMP_DIR as 'Path\Path\';
```

---

Ensure the user that will import the file has the privilige to Read & Write on the directory (In case you are not using SYS)

```
GRANT Read, Write ON DIRECTORY IMP_DIR TO user;
```

---

Then, include the directory parameter within the import statement

```
impdp 'sys AS SYSDBA' file=dump.dmp full=yes log=implog.txt directory=IMP_DIR
```